# String To Datetime 5/7/2013 07:42 53 AM C#

Tags: string, c#-4.0, datetime

I want to convert string to Datetime Format.
I am suing the following code but its giving me error.
Please help.

```
 DateTime dtCurrentFile =  DateTime.ParseExact(" 5/7/2013 07:42 53 AM ","d/M/yyyy HH:mm ss",null);
```

I am getting exception as:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (not sure if that's exactly right, I'm not on windows right now):

```
DateTime dtCurrentFile =  DateTime.ParseExact("5/7/2013 07:42 53 AM","d/M/yyyy hh:mm ss tt",null);
```

What has changed: using "tt" for "AM/PM", using "hh" for 12-hour clock.

Comment: I am getting one constant error while converting this value to the above type.7/4/2013 07:02 14 PM ..Whenever i convert this exception occurs invalid string type.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime dtCurrentFile =  DateTime.ParseExact("5/7/2013 07:42 53 AM","d/M/yyyy HH:mm ss tt",null);

I found this solution on net.